# Remove multiple text box in on-click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Adding multiple text-box using j-query

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="col-md-3"><label>Name</label><input type="text" class="form-control" name=""/></div>
<div class="col-md-2"><label>Count</label><input type="text" class="form-control" name=""/></div>
<div class="col-md-3"><label>Brand</label><input type="text" class="form-control" name=""/></div>
<div class="col-md-3"><label>Condition</label><input type="text" class="form-control" name=""/></div>
<div class="col-md-1" style="margin-top:30px;"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></div>
<div class="contents"></div>
</div>
```

And script like

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".add").click(function() {
$('<div class="col-md-3"><input type="text" class="form-control" name=""/></div>').appendTo(".contents");
$('<div class="col-md-2"><input type="text" class="form-control" name=""/></div>').appendTo(".contents");
$('<div class="col-md-3"><input type="text" class="form-control" name=""/></div>').appendTo(".contents");
$('<div class="col-md-3"><input type="text" class="form-control" name=""/></div>').appendTo(".contents");
$('<div class="col-md-1"><span class="rem" ><a href="javascript:void(0);" >Remove</span></div>').appendTo(".contents");
});
});
</script>
```

The above query is used to add multiple text box that properly working and i try to remove added items in remove button but that only remove one text box only i am using this script

```
<script>
$('.contents').on('click', '.rem', function() {
$(this).parent("div").remove();
});
</script>
```

any way to remove the clicked full row only ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKf9I.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated answer:** Use [prevUntil()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_prevuntil.asp) to achieve this:

```js
$('.contents').on('click', '.rem', function() {
    $(this).parent().prevUntil(".col-md-1").remove();
    $(this).parent().remove();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".add").click(function() {
        $('<div class="col-md-3"><input type="text" class="form-control" name=""/></div>').appendTo(".contents");
        $('<div class="col-md-2"><input type="text" class="form-control" name=""/></div>').appendTo(".contents");
        $('<div class="col-md-3"><input type="text" class="form-control" name=""/></div>').appendTo(".contents");
        $('<div class="col-md-3"><input type="text" class="form-control" name=""/></div>').appendTo(".contents");
        $('<div class="col-md-1"><span class="rem" ><a href="javascript:void(0);" >Remove</span><hr></div>').appendTo(".contents");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-3"><label>Name</label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="" /></div>
    <div class="col-md-2"><label>Count</label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="" /></div>
    <div class="col-md-3"><label>Brand</label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="" /></div>
    <div class="col-md-3"><label>Condition</label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="" /></div>
    <div class="col-md-1" style="margin-top:30px;">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">Add this</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="contents"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: remove only one row that based on the remove button see the image i click the remove button that delete only the red row only

Comment: pls see the image that show the full dtls only only coloum not textbox

Comment: @Shambu Check my answer again please

Comment: Glad to help you

Answer (score 3):

You can rewrite code like this. You are removing the container, that was the issue

```js
   

 $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".add").click(function() {
    var container= $('<div>');
    $('<div class="col-md-3"><input type="text" class="form-control" name=""/></div>').appendTo(container);
    $('<div class="col-md-2"><input type="text" class="form-control" name=""/></div>').appendTo(container);
    $('<div class="col-md-3"><input type="text" class="form-control" name=""/></div>').appendTo(container);
    $('<div class="col-md-3"><input type="text" class="form-control" name=""/></div>').appendTo(container);
    $('<div class="col-md-1"><span class="rem" ><a href="javascript:void(0);" >Remove</span></div>').appendTo(container);
    $('.childControl').after($(container).clone());
    });
    $('.contents').on('click', '.rem', function() {
    $(this).parent("div").parent("div").empty();
    });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="col-md-3"><label>Name</label><input type="text" class="form-control" name=""/></div>
<div class="col-md-2"><label>Count</label><input type="text" class="form-control" name=""/></div>
<div class="col-md-3"><label>Brand</label><input type="text" class="form-control" name=""/></div>
<div class="col-md-3"><label>Condition</label><input type="text" class="form-control" name=""/></div>
<div class="col-md-1" style="margin-top:30px;"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>Add</a></div>
<div class="contents"><div class="childControl"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: remove only one set of textboxes not all set you see the image that describe the details

Comment: @Sandeep P Pillai You dont have to specify the div just use $(this).parent().parent().remove();.This will also work.

Answer (score 0):

The parent should be grand parent, try below code

```
replace $(this).parent("div").remove();
```

with

```
$(this).parent().parent().remove();
```

so final code is:

```
<script>
$('.contents').on('click', '.rem', function() {
$(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
</script>
```

Comment: :- the remove function is working but remove all row i wand remove only on row and adding function not working in after removing after refresh that worked